# $1-1$ correspondence between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've started this topic and getting confused on one of the questions. Can someone please give me a brief understanding of how this works?

The question was to 'Construct a one-to-one correspondence between the set of natural numbers and the set of all integers'

Comment: Do you know what a one-to-one correspondence is? If not, what about a one-to-one function?

Answer (score 2):

Map the positive integers to the even naturals, and the negative integers to the odd naturals.

You might need to make a minor adjustment according to your definition of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f: \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{n}2 & n \text{ is even}\\
-\left(\dfrac{n-1}2\right) & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
Note that this map is one to one and also onto.

Comment: so you differentiate between -0 and 0?

Comment: Obviously not since that would give two different answers for n= 1.  Of course it would be better just to drop the unnecessary "0 if n= 1" line.

Comment: Thats what happens if you omit the smilie...

Comment: Done. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It looks like you have f(1) and f(0) both mapping to 0, so not 1-1  Easy enough to fix, though.